# Check that returns csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would a checkbox that when check will return csv and html if otherwise.
I follow this video and got the csv to work 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true

now I have a check_box_tag that is to be submitted with the form. if the check box is checked then it should render the csv.

```
=form_tag exams_path, method: :get do
  =text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
  =check_box_tag "csv"
  = submit_tag "Search by id", name: nil
```

Inside the controller it have

```
...
params[:format] = "csv" if params[:csv]
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv {render text:@exams.to_csv}
end
...
```

but this does not work.

Comment: I suspect that respond_to works off of request.format not params[:format]

Comment: So how do I change request.format to "csv"? or how do I make the checkbox change the request.format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out thanks to John.

I need:

```
request.format = :csv if params[:csv]
```

instead of my original

```
params[:format] = "csv" if params[:csv]
```

Dont know if changing format is the best way to go, but it just what I need.

Comment: If you figured it out thanks to another answer, then you need to select that answer as having solved it. If you did it without anyone else's help, then select your answer. It appears the correct thing to do would be to select his.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
if params[:csv]
  render text:@exams.to_csv
else
  render
end
```